# MDX - Changing Infinity Value to Zero

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx

I have a calculated measure which returns Infinity in some cases due to a NULL division.

My preference is just to change the MDX in the report rather than changing the cube etc. I want instead of infinity, which causes the 'Axis object - Auto interval error...' with a chart, to return 0 (zero) as this is the desired result.

So far I've tried IsNothing([Measures.Budgets]) and IIF([Measures.Budgets] = "Infinity", 0, [Measures.Budgets]) to no avail.

I'm quite new to MDX/SSAS so any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You have to resolve this inside your calculation definition for your Budgets measure. It should look something like this:

```
Iif ( Divisor = 0 , 0 , Numerator / Divisor )
```